# If $p$ is an odd prime and $\gcd(ab, p) = 1$, prove that at least one of $a, b$, or $ab$ is a quadratic residue of p.

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Anyone can check my proof ?
Consider $x^{2}\equiv ab \pmod p$
If it is congruence $\gcd (x^{2},p)$ must equal.
Since $\gcd(a b,p) = 1$ it follow $\gcd(x^{2},p)=\gcd(a,p)=\gcd(b,p)=1$
therefore it make the quardratric residues can be $a,b,ab$

Comment: Products of non-residues is a residue. This follows from elementary properties of the Legendre symbol. Hence, if $a$ and $b$ are non-residues, their product is a residue. Hence, one of $a,b,ab$ is a residue.

Comment: You don't need the condition $\gcd(ab,p)=1$, because $0$ is a quadratic residue.

Comment: Your proof makes no sense at all, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Tonyk I'm sorry to hear that I think it can prove by use properties of congruence about gcd. I think If it has both side has same gcd It might make it congruence.May be I jump into conclusion the number must be quardratic residues. Thank for comment